# A relationship database design (using MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relationship

Recently, I am trying to design a database solution that about "user relationship"—— each user has friends, each friend own an authority(authority describe the privacy level between their relationship). I am totally new in MySQL program, here is my two database design:

**design 1**: databse has an "user_table" that describe all users's base information such as user_id, age, email ... ,and **each user** has an "friends_table", "friends_table" contains the friend's user_id(can be queried the friend's information), each "friend_table" can be queried by its table name stored in "user_table"(each friend_table's name is unique).

```
user_table
+------------------------+
| user_name(primary key) |
+------------------------+
|        password        |
+------------------------+
|          email         |
+------------------------+
|         ....           |
+------------------------+
|         ....           |             friend_table
+------------------------+ ----------> +------------------------------+
|    friend_table_name   |             |          id(primary key)     |
+------------------------+             +------------------------------+
                                       |          user_name           |
                                       +------------------------------+
                                       |          authority           |
                                       +------------------------------+
                                       |             ....             |
                                       +------------------------------+
```

**design 2**: databse has an "user_table" and an "relationship_table". the "relationship_table" describe all user's relationship.

```
user_table                          relationship_table
+------------------------+          +------------------------+
| user_name(primary key) |          |     id(primary key)    |
+------------------------+          +------------------------+
|        password        |          |        user_name       |
+------------------------+          +------------------------+
|          email         |          |       friend_name      |
+------------------------+          +------------------------+
|         ....           |          |        authority       |
+------------------------+          +------------------------+
|         ....           |          |          ....          |
+------------------------+          +------------------------+
```

base on design 2, a user named Jim has 4 friend Lisa, Tom, Jerry and Johnny, the tbales show as below:

```
user_table            
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| user_name | password  |      email    |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|    Jim    |   *****   |  Jim@mail.com |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|   LiLei   |   *****   |  LiLei@gl.com |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|   ....    |   *****   |     ....      |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|   ....    |   *****   |     ....      |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+

relationship_table            
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     id    | user_name |  friend_name  |   authority   |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     1     |    Jim    |      Lisa     |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     2     |    Jim    |      Tom      |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     3     |    Jim    |     Jerry     |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     4     |    Jim    |     Johnny    |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     5     |    Qing   |      Jim      |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     6     |    Feng   |      Tom      |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|     7     |    Guang  |      Tom      |     ***       |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

if I want to query Jim's friend, I use the SQL command:

```
 select friend_name from relationship_table where user_name='Jim';
```

consider to the Database performance, these 2 designs which is the better one? or there is a better design exist?

Comment: Search for "nested set model"

Comment: design 1 isn't even an option

Answer (score 0):

Basically even friends are users(assumed), therefore Add all people to one single table.

So the Basic tables would be

UserTable (UserID,user_name[primary key],password,email, .... )
 UserID--> is just a simple auto increment number

AuthorityTable(AuthorityID,Authority_name,Permission,....)
AuthorityID--> is just a simple auto increment number

UserRelationShipTable (URID,UserID,FriendsWith,AuthorityID)

> URID--> is just a simple auto increment number
>    UserID--> here is foreign key from UserTable
>    FriendsWith --> is also userID which resembles Friends
>    AuthorityID --> foreign key from AuthorityTable.